# Merging two rasters, obtain only highest values, overwrite raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, mosaic, map-algebra

In order to run a hydrologigal analysis I'd like to to merge two raster datasets (DEM and  buildings) to get as result one raster **with only the highest values (elevations)** of both. In other words: To overlay the DEM with the buildings and to use the buildings-values whenever possible.

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.4 (ArcMap/ArcScene) for this.

I've got the following input data:

- DEM as raster
- builidungs as raster (with Null-values outside the buildings)

I was wondering if its possible to use an IF-statement in the Map Algebra Tool, but didn't get the right syntax or maybe there is a better way to do it.
The If-statement could be similar to this: 
If ("buildings1" IS Null, "DEM1")

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this just by using the [Mosaic to New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) geoprocessing tool. Just choose maximum for your Mosaic Operator and the new raster will use the high value anywhere that they overlap.